# Java: How to generate unique Long ID?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create method that generate unique ID. I can't use " return id++" because of final variable. Is there any other options?

```
public class Job {

        private final long id;
        private final int difficulty;
        private final String owner;

        public Job(int difficulty, String owner) {
            this.id = nextId();
            this.difficulty= difficulty;
            this.owner= owner;
        }

        public long nextId(){
            return id;
        }
```

I also tried java.util.UUID. It is possible generate unique ID with final variable?

```
private final String id;
...
public String nextId(){
    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return id;
```

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: You have a `final` variable, and you're trying to change it? No, it's not possible. This smells a lot like an XY problem, what are you trying to use this to solve? If you're wanting jobs to have unique IDs (and aren't worried about concurrency), keep a non-final static variable in the class that represents the global highest unused job ID, then in the constructor of each object set the new job's `final` ID to that value and increment it.

Comment: Look into static variable types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *two* variables: one static one which counts the IDs already given, and one final one which holds the ID for each object.

```
public class Job {
    private static long nextId = 0L;

    private final long id;
    private final int difficulty;
    private final String owner;

    public Job(int difficulty, String owner) {
        this.id = nextId++;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // ...
}
```

If this also needs to work in a multithreaded environment, you must use synchronization or atomic operations (for example, `AtomicLong`):

```
public class Job {
    private static AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong();

    private final long id;
    private final int difficulty;
    private final String owner;

    public Job(int difficulty, String owner) {
        this.id = nextId.getAndIncrement();
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // ...
}
```